# Exception handling issue in project reactor and also retry failed transaction

Tags: java, reactive-programming, reactor

I was testing my code for the error handling part.Looks like its not working as expected.I have broke down the code snippet as show below.Overall addenda is to retry 5 time when there is exception.For simplicity I have written a method to throw NPE exception and added a error handler.Can some one explain what is wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Mono.just( errorDemo() )
        .retry(5)
        .doOnError( e -> log.error( "Error {}", e.getStackTrace() ) )
        .doOnSuccess( e -> log.info( "done" ) );
}
public static Mono<Void> errorDemo() {
    return Mono.error( NullPointerException::new ); // throwing back 
exception to calling method
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should subscribe your Mono. Nothing happens if you don't subscribe.

You could add `.block()` for your example.